# Using encore dev-server with docker devilbox containers

Tags: docker, devilbox

I'm trying to use dev-server in docker containers with **devilbox**.

Devilbox port: 80 and host: 127.0.0.1.

I did all configuration to use dev-server in virtual machine that i found: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/virtual-machine.html
But in chrome consol i have this error:

```
GET http://inmogence.loc/build/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):98 GET http://inmogence.loc/build/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

And also i dont have autorefreshing window when i save.

I do the command `$ yarn dev-server` and tha answer is:

```
devilbox@php-7.4.9 in /shared/httpd/inmogence/symfony $ yarn dev-server
yarn run v1.22.4
$ encore dev-server --public http://inmogence.loc:80 --host 127.0.0.1
Running webpack-dev-server ...

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://inmogence.loc:80/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from http://inmogence.loc:80/build/
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /shared/httpd/inmogence/symfony/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 866ms                                             9:14:39 PM

 WAIT  Compiling...                                                               9:57:12 PM

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 73ms
```

So it look that its working.

My webpack.config.js:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    //.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And my package.json:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.30.0",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server --public http://inmogence.loc:80 --host 127.0.0.1",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
}
```

My build/manifest.json:

```
{
  "build/app.css": "http://inmogence.loc:80/build/app.css",
  "build/app.js": "http://inmogence.loc:80/build/app.js",
  "build/runtime.js": "http://inmogence.loc:80/build/runtime.js",
  "build/vendors~app.js": "http://inmogence.loc:80/build/vendors~app.js"
}
```

And my entrypoints.json:

```
{
  "entrypoints": {
    "app": {
      "js": [
        "http://inmogence.loc:80/build/runtime.js",
        "http://inmogence.loc:80/build/vendors~app.js",
        "http://inmogence.loc:80/build/app.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "http://inmogence.loc:80/build/app.css"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So any solution ?